# WiFi not working after latest Ubuntu software update

Tags: networking, wireless, dell

I have a Dell laptop running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
I purchased it new about a month ago.
This morning I got a popup about a Software Update available, so I updated, and now the wifi is not working at all.
I checked the networking menu and it shows NO networks detected.
Everything worked just fine until this latest software update.

Here's the output from   lspci -knn | grep Net -A2

> 3a:00.0 Network Contoller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
>
> ```
>          Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0050]
> ```
>
> 3b:00.0 Unassingned class [ff00]:  Realtek Semiconductor Co. ltd. Device [10ec:525a] (rev 01)

I tried the mokutil disable validation as described in the other problem report

> sudo apt install mokutil
>   sudo mokutil --disable-validation

it forced me to create a new password, but still no wifi!!!

Here is lspci -vvnn
3a.00.0 Network Controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
Subsytem : Intel Corporation Device [8086:0050]
Control: I/O- Mem- BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParERR- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- SERR-

What driver should I have for the Intel 8260?   I did lmod and I didn't see anything that looked like a wifi driver...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get "Required key not available" when install DKMS modules?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-dkms-modules)

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: I did not get any error about "Required key not available" and have NEVER installed any "DKMS modules", is this still the same issue?

Comment: Will this happen after EVERY Ubuntu software update?

Comment: Did the update include a kernel upgrade?

Comment: Let's see what you installed ot not. Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: @http://askubuntu.com/users/571701/mattb: You don't "add newlines to a comment"! You "Edit" the original post and add the information, with formatting.

Comment: How do I tell if a software update includes a kernel upgrade?

Answer (score 2):

I booted in to the Bios Menu page, but hitting F-12 when the Dell logo appeared during boot up... 
I found the SecureBootMode setting under the Security settings, and disabled it, then after rebooting everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you installed a custom dkms driver to support your 8260 adapter. You can check it by

```
dkms status
```

terminal command.

Secure Boot does not allow to load 3rd party unsigned kernel modules.

Now Intel 8260 adapters are supported by new Ubuntu kernels.

The best solution will be to remove that dkms module and upgrade the kernel to 4.4 by running

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-xenial
```

This way the wireless adapter will work with Secure Boot on and you will not depend on kernel compatibility with a custom module.

Comment: NO, I didn't install any custom dkms driver, unless it came with the most recent sofware update...  Or it was pre-installed on this computer as part of this Dell/Ubuntu load..

Comment: I edited the BIOS to disable Secure Boot and it seems to be fine now.

Comment: What should I look for in dkms status?